Real roots of $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+1=0,$ when $a,b,c$ are real and $b\ge\frac{a^2+c^2}{4}$
For real $a,b,c$ and
$$b \ge \frac{a^2+c^2}{4}\tag{*}$$
the given polynomial equation
$$f(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+1=0\tag{**}$$
can be re-written  as
$$f(x)=(x^2+ax/2)^2+(b-a^2/4-c^2/4)x^2+(cx/2+1)^2\ge 0\tag{***}$$
In $(***)$, the equality holds only when $x=-a/2=-2/c$
So the equation $(**)$ will have non real root or two real coincident roots as $x=-a/2$ or $x=-2/c,$ if $ac=4$ with condition $(*)$ equality.
Question:
How else the roots of $(**)$ under the condition $(*)$ can be analysed , without going via $(***)$ ?

I think you have a typo somewhere because the second formulation is not a fourth degree polynomial.

Thanks corrected now

There is some symmetry in this equation between the polynomial $P(a, b, c) = x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+1$ and the polynomial $P(c, b, a)$. If $x$ is a zero of $P(a, b, c)$ then $x^{-1}$ is a zero of $P(c, b, a)$.
Another fact you can deduce is that all zeroes of this polynomial need to multiply to 1. Because the zeroes appear in conjugate pairs, this is equivalent to their moduli being each others inverse.
There is still some difference between the characterisation of 2 complex conjugate pairs with inverse moduli and the zeroes of a polynomial as described. If $a \neq c$ then the condition $b \geq \frac{a^2+c^2}{4}$ is strictly stronger than the polynomial not having any real zeroes.
